# Create variable BASH command

Tags: bash, variables, command

I try to customize a little BASH script for special proprose.

I'm confuse with BASH scripting when it come time to assigne a command to a variable.

My broken code:

```
if [ -n "$2" ]
then
    top=`| head -n $2`
fi
awk '{print $17, ">", $19;}' $logs_folder$i | sort -g | uniq -c | sort -r -g $top
```

So by default it return all line but if the user specified a number, it will add the head  command

Comment: Here you can read why you should not put commands in variables: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array form instead:

```
if [ -n "$2" ]
then
    top=(head -n "$2")
else
    top=(cat)
fi
awk '{print $17, ">", $19;}' "$logs_folder$i" | sort -g | uniq -c | sort -r -g | "${top[@]}"
```

And try to add more quotes ("").

Actually you can't save pipe to a variable and let bash parse it the normal way when it's expanded but you can replace it with another command instead (cat).

You could actually use eval but it's pretty delicate:

```
if [ -n "$2" ]
then
    top="| head -n \"\$2\""
fi
eval "awk '{print $17, \">\", \$19;}' \"\$logs_folder\$i\" | sort -g | uniq -c | sort -r -g $top"
```

Comment: Nice try to remplace it with cat. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A working script would look like this:

```
# set propper default value
top=""
if [ -n "$2" ]
then
    # use double quotes instead of back-tics
    # back-tics are for command substitution
    # but you need the command itself as a string
    top="| head -n $2"
fi

awk '{print $17, ">", $19;}' "$logs_folder$i" | sort -g | uniq -c | sort -r -g $top
```